# Редирект с page.php на razdel/page.php

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Здравствуйте! 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как c помощью .htaccess сделать редирект со страницы вида 
site.ru/page.php на страницу site.ru/razdel/page.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант вот так:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ /razdel/page.php [R=301, L]
```